# Getting all the substrings as keys and their occurcences as values with hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

**Problem:** Given a string, I want to get all the substrings of `length = k` using `Hash Map`.

So I've declared a `public static function getHistogram` which returns `Map<String,Integer>` and I'm trying to use a HashMap to get all the sub strings (as keys) of that given string, and every sub string that already occured in the string, I want to increment the value in its key (will be the counter).

This is what I've got so far: **Currenet output:** outputs not as expected.

```
  import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main2{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidValueException{
        // Get a set of the entries
          Set set = Main2.getHistogram("ababaca", 5).entrySet();

          // Get an iterator
          Iterator i = set.iterator();

          // Display elements
          while(i.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
             System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
             System.out.println(me.getValue());
          }
          System.out.println();
    }

    public static Map<String,Integer> getHistogram(String str, int k)
        throws InvalidValueException
    {
        int i,j;
        String tempStr;

        Map<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
          {
            for(j=i; j < str.length(); j++){
                tempStr = str.substring(i, j);
                int count = hmap.containsKey(tempStr) ? hmap.get(tempStr) : 0;
                hmap.put(tempStr, count + 1);
            }

          }
        return hmap;    
    }
}
```

Edit: Has to use count + 1 instead of count++, but still not fixed entirely.

Output:

```
: 7
a: 3
ab: 2
aba: 2
b: 2
bab: 1
ac: 1
c: 1
bac: 1
abac: 1
abab: 1
baba: 1
babac: 1
ababa: 1
ababac: 1
ba: 2
```

Comment: "of length k", but I don't  see, where is k used

Comment: @matoni I know, it is not used because I'm trying to get all the lengths first, when I succeed I'll just edit it accordingly.

Comment: so what is the expected behaviour before you filter out from the map all substrings of length k?

Comment: @matoni As I mentioned in the previous comment, I want to output all the substrings and their occurences in the given string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Substr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getHistogram("ababaca", 5));
        System.out.println(getHistogram("ababaca", 4));
        System.out.println(getHistogram("ababaca", 3));
        System.out.println(getHistogram("ababaca", 2));
        System.out.println(getHistogram("ababaca", 1));
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> getHistogram(String str, int k) {
        Map<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        for (int start = 0; start < str.length() - k + 1; start++) {
            String substring = str.substring(start, start + k);
            int count = hmap.containsKey(substring) ? hmap.get(substring) : 0;
            hmap.put(substring, count + 1);
        }
        return hmap;
    }    
}
```

This seems to yield the correct results.

If `k` is fixed, you don't need two loops, just one. It just runs through the beginning indices of possible substrings. Then we take the substring and count the number of substrings as you initially suggested.

Comment: You're right. I went too far with my implementation. Thank you Roman/

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you can do this in a straightforward manner:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getHistogram(String string, int k) {
    return 
        k > string.length() ? Collections.emptyMap() :
        k == string.length() ? Collections.singletonMap(string, 1L) :
            IntStream.range(0, string.length() - k + 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> string.substring(i, i + k))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Function.identity(),
                    Collectors.counting()));
}
```

This first checks whether `k` is greater than the length of the given `string`. If `k` is greater, it returns an empty map (you could also throw an `IllegalArgumentException`).

Then, it checks if `k` is equal to the length of the given `string`, in which case a singleton map with the `string` and `1L` is returned.

Finally, if `k < string.length()`, we create a range of integers that goes from `0` (inclusive) to `string.length() - k + 1` (exclusive). Then, each one of these intergers is transformed to a substring that starts in the `i`-th position of `string` and **always** takes `k` characters. (This is different than in your implementation, where in the first iteration you take `0` characters, in the second you take `1`, etc). If I understood your question correctly, you'd always have to take `k` characters, until you reach the end of `string`.

Then, all these substrings are collected to a `Map` via the `Collectors.groupingBy` collector, which expects a function that maps each element of the stream (these would be the substrings in your case) to the keys of the map. As we want the actual substrings to be the keys of the map, I've used the identity function. `Collectors.counting` just puts the count for each substring as the value.

If you want the substrings to appear in the same order they are taken from the `string`, you can use the version of `Collectors.grouping` that accepts a map supplier, and tell it to use a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves insertion order:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getHistogram(String string, int k) {
    return
        k > string.length() ? Collections.emptyMap() :
        k == string.length() ? Collections.singletonMap(string, 1L) :
            IntStream.range(0, string.length() - k + 1)
                .mapToObj(i -> string.substring(i, i + k))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Function.identity(),
                    LinkedHashMap::new, // <-- here's the map supplier
                    Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Comment: That it a nice solution Federico. But I'd rather stick with the more understandable implementation. Thanks!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS No worries, my answer just complements Roman's answer. Now readers will have 2 ways to solve the problem you posted.